# Matching points in table to polygons

Tags: polygon, sql, vba, point-in-polygon

this is my first post to this forum. I hope to start participating actively.

I have a table with several records (aprox 200.000), each with its own coordinates. And I need to identify the "Polygon" where each point belongs (I got another table with the vertex for earch polygon) . I am working with Excel and Access at this point. Thanks for the help!

(the polygons doesn’t have holes and doesn’t overlap with other polygon)

I know there is an algorithm that checks if the number of times a line cross another line from the desired point to another point is even, the point is inside polygon, if the number is odd, the point is outside the polygon. But I don’t know how to implement this. Here are some reference links with the algorithm:

http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/

Here is a sample:

I got a table similar to this:

- Point_ID / Coordinates
- 1 / -70.559349,-33.411913
- 2 / -70.579004,-33.407542
- etc. (aprox. 200.000 points)

And I got the following table defining the boundaries of each polygon:

- Polygon_ID / Polygon_Sequence / Coordinates
- 1 / 1 / -70.567331,-33.408803
- 1 / 2 / -70.584755,-33.414249
- 1 / 3 / -70.586987,-33.409692
- 1 / 4 / -70.585527,-33.404175
- 1 / 5 / -70.571537,-33.398084
- 1 / 6 / -70.567331,-33.408803
- 2 / 1 / -70.567245,-33.409047
- 2 / 2 / -70.564756,-33.416570
- 2 / 3 / -70.552998,-33.418576
- 2 / 4 / -70.551796,-33.408474
- 2 / 5 / -70.560122,-33.407542
- 2 / 6 / -70.562525,-33.407327
- 2 / 7 / -70.567245,-33.409047
- etc...

So, this is the output I need (in **bold**):

- Point_ID / Coordinates / **Polygon_ID**
- 1 / -70.559349,-33.411913 / **2**
- 2 / -70.579004,-33.407542 / **1**
- etc...

Thanks a lot!
Alejandro